# Shell script check if there are any running process in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a script that will run automatically a CFD model with many cases in different directories. Then i want to check if a directory have already running process, script will warn the user and do not execute in that directory.

So is there any way to check it?

Please help me!

Comment: `lsof` or `fuser`?

Comment: By "in a directory", you mean what? That another process *has the directory open*? That an executable in the directory is being run? Does a shell cd'd into that directory count? Any other process, or just another copy of the same script? This is very vague as presently written.

Comment: hi you!
my script will enter to each directory and run an application in there, such as PimpleFoam,..
And I want to check if this directory has already run PimpleFoam.

Answer (score 0):

The best-practice way is to have each the scripts you want to prevent from running concurrently grab a lock in the directory.

Assuming your operating system is Linux, `flock` is an appropriate tool for the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

# open lockfile in current directory
# if operating on a directory given as an argument, update appropriately
exec 99>.lock

# grab a lock
flock -x 99 || {
  echo "Could not grab lock" >&2
  exit 1
}

# do your other calculations here
```

---

Also see:

- [The bash-hackers Mutex HOWTO page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex)
- [BashFAQ #45](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)